# Convert HTTP response Raw formatted data in to JSON format

Tags: java, json

Is there any API in java for converting HTTP Raw format response output in to JSON format and vice-versa.

Comment: What is "HTTP Raw format"? HTTP is a data-transfer protocol - it doesn't say anything about what's in the message body.

Comment: This question is currently nonsense. Voting to close. user591790, if you can explain what you want to know in more detail, you will get some answers. If you don't, you'll get more close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.json.org/java/, specifically HTTP.java

From the HTTP class javadoc description in HTTP.java:

> Convert an HTTP header to a JSONObject and back.